# Is it safe to configure the default Documents folders of two users to be symbolic links to the same folder on another drive?

Tags: mklink

In other words:

There are two user profiles on a Windows 10 PC. Let's call them User_A and User_B.

A Documents folder already exists on D:.

Using an elevated command prompt...

Navigate to c:\users\User_A and delete the Documents folder.
Then run the following command:
mklink /J "c:\users\User_A\Documents" "D:\Documents"

Navigate to c:\users\User_B and delete the Documents folder.
Then run the following command:
mklink /J "c:\users\User_B\Documents" "D:\Documents"

That way, when either user is logged in and works on files in the default Documents folder the changes will be available to both users.

I realize there are alternative approaches to let them work on the same files but this keeps things easy and by default for the users.

Comment: I think the symbolic link is not needed, beginning with Windows 7 you can change the location of user folders like Documents, Images... from the folder properties.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, there should be no need for symbolic links.

**Replacing Documents**

1. Open *File Explorer* from the start menu.
2. From the left-hand *Quick Access* panel, highlight *Documents*. Right-click the icon and choose *Properties*.
3. Under the *Location* tab, enter the full path for the existing folder you wish to use as the *Documents* folder. If the folder doesn't exist, Windows will offer to create it for you. Click *Apply*.
4. You may wish to click *No* when it offers to manually move documents (since I am honestly unsure if actually does any erasing of the destination contents).
5. Once you've made a decision, simply click *OK* to finalize everything (you can move documents manually from the old location if you choose not to have Windows move them for you).

The only minor drawbacks to this solution are:

- Windows will represent the new folder as *Documents* even if it is named something else.
- The old Documents folder might still be there (depending on your previous choices above) so you may want to delete it (typically *C:\Users\Username\Documents*). Note this default location can be restored with the same steps as listed above.
- Depending on your changes, you may have to re-pin the *Documents* folder to the *Quick Access* layout (usually if you restore the default location).

**Pin A Folder**

As a slightly less cumbersome option, any folder can be pinned to the *Quick Access* menu. Simply open the folder in *File Explorer*, highlight then right-click the *Quick Access* item in the left-hand pane and select *Pin Current Folder To Quick Access*. This folder will appear with *Documents*, etc. and should be easy to select in most instances.

**Safety**

Regarding the "safety" of doing a similar thing with symbolic links, I would be hesitant simply because Windows has it's own way of dealing with these kinds of special user folders which may or may not work properly with such links.